# undefined reference with Cmakelists.txt

Tags: ros, xbee, catkin

In my project, I want to use [xbee external library](https://github.com/digidotcom/xbee_ansic_library) with [ROS](http://www.ros.org/).
Originally when I make exe file I use makefile. But since ROS use catkin, I have to make exe file with `Cmakelists.txt`
But I'm stuck on same error `undefined reference ..`, Even I followed every direction that I can.

My Project's directory structure is looks like this.

```
.
├── xbee_ansic_library
    ├── include - 3 subdirectories have h file
        ├── wpan
        ├── xbee
        └── zigbee
    ├── src - subdirectories have c file
        ├── wpan
        ├── xbee
        └── zigbee            
└── my_project
        ├── src
            └── main.cpp
        └── CMakeLists.txt
```

and since original makefile was look like [this](https://github.com/digidotcom/xbee_ansic_library/blob/master/samples/posix/Makefile), I wrote my_project/CmakeLists.txt like below.

```
project(my_project)

## Declare a catkin package
catkin_package()

# %EndTag(FULLTEXT)%

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(~/catkin_ws/src/xbee_ansic_library/include)
include_directories(~/catkin_ws/src/my_project/include)

LINK_DIRECTORIES(~/catkin_ws/src/xbee_ansic_library/src)
LINK_DIRECTORIES(~/catkin_ws/src/my_project/src)

add_library(base_OBJECTS 
${xbee_ansic_library_SRC_POSIX}/xbee_platform_posix.c 
${xbee_ansic_library_SRC_POSIX}/xbee_serial_posix.c
${xbee_ansic_library_SRC_UTIL}/hexstrtobyte.c  
${xbee_ansic_library_SRC_UTIL}/memcheck.c 
${xbee_ansic_library_SRC_UTIL}/swapbytes.c 
${xbee_ansic_library_SRC_UTIL}/swapcpy.c 
${xbee_ansic_library_SRC_UTIL}/hexdump.c src/parse_serial_args.c)

add_library(xbee_OBJECTS 
${base_OBJECTS} 
${xbee_ansic_library_SRC_WPAN}/wpan_types.c
${xbee_ansic_library_SRC_XBEE}/xbee_device.c 
${xbee_ansic_library_SRC_XBEE}/xbee_atcmd.c)

....


add_executable(main src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main ${catkin_LIBRARIES} main_OBJECTS)
add_dependencies(main my_project_generate_messages_cpp)
```

But when I command with `catkin_make`, I got error

> CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
>   main.cpp:(.text+0x177): undefined reference to`xbee_dev_dump_settings'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

But `xbee_dev_dump_settings` is in the `xbee_ansic_library/include/xbee/device.h`, `xbee_ansic_library/src/xbee/xbee_device.c`.
Since error is `undefined reference ..` not, `not declared ..` I think I did well with headers.

What should have to do next?

Answer (score 0):

The error is at the linking stage so it is probably related to your `target_link_libraries` line. I believe it should also specify the xbee and base libraries you create so changing it to this should work:

```
target_link_libraries(main ${catkin_LIBRARIES} base_OBJECTS xbee_OBJECTS)
```